# Why isn't there a static initializer in Python?

Tags: object-oriented, python, static-methods, static-access, decorator

The equivalent of

```
static {
    // Code here
}
```

does not exist in Python by default. The closest thing, while being "Pythonic", seems to be to [create a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13900861/3395831) and do the initialization there such as:

```
def static_initialization_decorator_for_myclass(cls):
    cls.initialize_static_stuff()
    return cls

@static_initialization_decorator_for_myclass
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def initialize_static_stuff():
        # Code here
```

Creating a new decorator for each class to do the same thing does not make sense. So, I thought of creating a standard decorator (say "initializestatic") and let that decorator call a given method name (say "init_static") like:

```
def initializestatic(cls):
    cls.init_static()
    return cls

@initializestatic
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def init_static():
        # Code here
```

This way, I can always use the same decorator and whenever I need a static initializer, I would put the following method in a class and would put `@initializestatic` decorator on top of the class:

```
@classmethod
def init_static():
    # Code here
```

Given it is that simple, why isn't there a built-in solution for static initialization in Python? I know that this sounds like a rant rather than a question but I am curious of the possible motives for excluding a static initializer from Python.

Comment: [Is asking “why” on language specs still considered as “primary opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601)

Comment: “The equivalent of `static { }`” *in what language…?*

Comment: given this limitation, this is an elegant solution though

Answer (score 8):

> ... why isn't there a built-in solution for static initialization in Python?

There is, you just put static initialization stuff in the class definition, i.e.

```
>>> class myclass:
...     print "anything in the class definition will be executed once!"
...     val = 42
...     def __init__(self,v):
...             self.v = v
...     def pr(self):
...             print self.v, self.val, myclass.val
...     def set(self,v):
...             self.val = v
...     def clsset(self, v):
...             myclass.val = v
...
anything in the class definition will be executed once!
>>> m = myclass(1)
>>> m.pr()
1 42 42
>>> m.set(2)
>>> m.clsset(24)
>>> m.pr()
1 2 24
>>> mm = myclass(2)
>>> mm.pr()
2 24 24
>>> mm.set(42)
>>> mm.pr()
2 42 24
```

Edit: I used print as an example of an arbitrary piece of code; here is another example:

```
>>> class myclass:
...     val = 42
...     dv = val * 1.2
...     def pr(self):
...             print self.dv
...
>>> m = myclass()
>>> m.pr()
50.4
```

Comment: But you cannot refer to anything in class. For example, you cannot do `double_val = val * 2` or `double_val = myclass.val * 2`. These won't work.

Comment: @Utku Are you sure? Something like `double_val = val * 2` should work. If not, consider asking on Stack Overflow. Note that the class body is executed like a function body and then a class is created with any local variables as class members, so you cannot reference `myclass` within the class definition.

Comment: Some simple actions can be performed this way, but I don't see any means to call the classes' static methods

Comment: @user508402 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718272/2075630. The static method objects contain a `__func__` field containing the function itself. Arguably, it would be more intuitive if they were callable though.

Comment: @kdb: while the static function can be called that way, class initialization is still not possible since the class is not accessible. The method has as __class__ attribute, but it points to 'staticmethod'.